# PHP Uploading images to an external host

Tags: php, image, external, host, uploading

I have a website and I would like to allow visitors to upload images. I want these images to be stored somewhere so that I can check them out and maybe put them on the website.

The 'problem' is that the server doesn't have much space, so if possible I don't want to keep the images on the server and instead have the website right away upload the images to for example a Google+ album.(Doesn't have to be Google+, just an example)

So, what I want:
* Have users upload images.
* Store the images somewhere else so that it doesn't fill up the server
* Be able to check out these images myself

What would be the best way to achieve this? (If it's possible to begin with)

Comment: I suggest hiring someone since you've chosen not attempt anything yourself.

Comment: Yeah, try something yourself and show us your code - other than that we won't solve your troubles for you.
Although I can assure you it is possible. The best way in my opinion would be uploading the file to your server and then move it to another (with some sort of remote service) and then delete it from your server.

Comment: You might find some info about uploading APIs here: https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/media/insert

Answer (score 0):

From what I learn that you can run an image hosting service for your website, and upload images via REST api.

Take a look at ImageS3, https://github.com/images3/images3-play, with this, you can upload you images to Amazon S3. and manage these images via ImageS3 web admin console.

Hope this answer can help you a little.